# R: sort by multiple columns with a specific order in each column (not ascending)

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, multiple-columns

Thank you very much for spending time helping this..
I have a data set named "MyData" as below: I want to sort the whole data set(A to E) with a specific order with column A,B and C. The order can be defined by me.
First sorting by A, with the order: "yellow", "green", then "red"
After A is sorting, then sorting by column B, with the order "X", "Z" then "Y"
After A and B is sorting, then sorting by C, the order should be the largest number to the smallest number.

```
     A          B         C          D          E        
1  red         X        0.8        aaaa        111
2  yellow      Y        0.2        dddd        222
3  green       X        0.3        cccc        111
4  yellow      Z        0.6        dddd        333
5  green       Y        0.1        aaaa        123
6  yellow      X        0.5        cccc        324
7  yellow      X        0.4        zzzz        222
8  yellow      X        0.8        bbbb        126
```

Below is my desired output:

```
     A         B         C          D          E 
8  yellow      X        0.8        bbbb        126
6  yellow      X        0.5        cccc        324
7  yellow      X        0.4        zzzz        222
4  yellow      Z        0.6        dddd        333
2  yellow      Y        0.2        dddd        222
3  green       X        0.3        cccc        111
5  green       Y        0.1        aaaa        123
1  red         X        0.8        aaaa        111
```

My actual dataset contains around 100 rows.
Thank you very much!!!:)

Comment: It is a bad idea to share your data through images. Please see this link to learn how to make reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create factor columns and specify the level to arrange the column. The last `mutate_if` is optional, which is just converting the factor back to character.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(A = factor(A, level = c("yellow", "green", "red")),
         B = factor(B, c("X", "Z", "Y"))) %>%
  arrange(A, B, desc(C)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
dat2
#        A B   C    D   E
# 1 yellow X 0.8 bbbb 126
# 2 yellow X 0.5 cccc 324
# 3 yellow X 0.4 zzzz 222
# 4 yellow Z 0.6 dddd 333
# 5 yellow Y 0.2 dddd 222
# 6  green X 0.3 cccc 111
# 7  green Y 0.1 aaaa 123
# 8    red X 0.8 aaaa 111
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "     A          B         C          D          E        
1  red         X        0.8        aaaa        111
2  yellow      Y        0.2        dddd        222
3  green       X        0.3        cccc        111
4  yellow      Z        0.6        dddd        333
5  green       Y        0.1        aaaa        123
6  yellow      X        0.5        cccc        324
7  yellow      X        0.4        zzzz        222
8  yellow      X        0.8        bbbb        126",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: it works...thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or in base R:

```
df[order(
    factor(df$A, levels = c("yellow", "green", "red")),
    factor(df$B, levels = c("X", "Z", "Y")),
    -df$C), ]
#    A B   C    D   E
#8 yellow X 0.8 bbbb 126
#6 yellow X 0.5 cccc 324
#7 yellow X 0.4 zzzz 222
#4 yellow Z 0.6 dddd 333
#2 yellow Y 0.2 dddd 222
#3  green X 0.3 cccc 111
#5  green Y 0.1 aaaa 123
#1    red X 0.8 aaaa 111
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "     A          B         C          D          E
1  red         X        0.8        aaaa        111
2  yellow      Y        0.2        dddd        222
3  green       X        0.3        cccc        111
4  yellow      Z        0.6        dddd        333
5  green       Y        0.1        aaaa        123
6  yellow      X        0.5        cccc        324
7  yellow      X        0.4        zzzz        222
8  yellow      X        0.8        bbbb        126", header = T)
```